# Computing a polynomial product over roots of unity

Tags: nt.number-theory

I'm trying to compute the coefficients of the following polynomial, where $\omega$ is a primitive $p$-th root of unity, for $p$ prime:

$$a(x) = \prod_{i=0}^{p-1} f(\omega^ix).$$

It turns out that the $i$-th coefficient is always an integer, and non-zero only when $i$ is a multiple of $p$. So it seems to me like there should be an elementary expression for $a$.

So far I've got this expression for the $i$-th coefficient:
$$a_i = x^i\sum_{k_0 + \ldots + k_{p-1} = i}f_{k_0} \cdots f_{k_{p-1}} \omega^{k_1 + 2k_2 + \ldots + (p-1)k_{p-1}}$$

where each $k_i$ is non-negative and bounded by the degree of $f$.

Clearly the roots of unity all cancel out somehow, but I can't figure out how to get a 'nice' expression out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know the roots of $f$? If $f(x)=c\prod_{i < d}(x-\alpha_i)$, then $a$ is easily seen to be $(-1)^{d(p+1)}c^p\prod_{i < d}(x^p-\alpha_i^p)$.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't know the roots of $f$. Thanks anyway though, that's interesting to know.

Comment: The last (i.e. degree zero) coefficient is just the $p$-th power of the last coefficient of $f$. Other than that, I suspect that there's no "nice" expression for the coefficients of $a$: for example, already for the first nontrivial coefficient (the one in degree $p\cdot\deg f$), the expression involves all of the coefficients of $f$. Computing this coefficient is related to Newton's identities (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities ).

Comment: We may assume that $f(0)=1$. If $g(x)=\log f(x) = g_1x+g_2x^2+\cdots$
then $\log a(x) = p(g_px^p+g_{2p}x^{2p}+\cdots)$. We can then compute
$a(x)$ by exponentiation. This will give a formula for $a(x)$ not
involving roots of unity, but it won't be pretty. On the other hand,
there are fast algorithms for computing log and exp of a power
series. 

Comment: "The $i$th coefficient is always an integer, and non-zero only when $i$ is a multiple of $p$". I guess $f\in\mathbf{Z}[x]$? If so then the coefficients are rational, by Galois theory, and integers because they're algebraic integers, and vanish if $i$ isn't a multiple of $p$ because if $F$ is the product then $F(\omega x)=F(x)$. However, "seems to me like there should be an elementary expression"---doesn't really follow as far as I can see. Take a random recurrence relation like $a(n+2)=n^2*a(n+1)+a(n)^2$ with $a(1)=a(2)=38$. Then all $a(n)$ are clearly integers but why expect a nice formula?


Comment: The map is the norm from $k[x]$ to its subring $k[x^n]$ --- $n$ being prime has nothing to do with it. So Emil's answer is, I think, the most helpful. You're asking, given a polynomial, for the polynomial whose roots are the $n$-th powers of the original roots, and I'm not aware of an easy way of getting this.

Comment: Notice that $a(1)$ can be expressed as the determinant of a circulant matrix formed by the coefficients of $f(x)$: 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirculantDeterminant.html

Comment: Here is an old and short article but look for papers citing it to perhaps find the state of the art for doing what you want: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.40.8452&rep=rep1&type=pdf

We describe  a general transformation of polynomials, and show that the classical deep relationships between the problems :(T ) transforming equations by a morphism(R) elementary elimination theory by resultants(S) change of bases for symmetric polynomials can be illustrated in Computer Algebra. Actually they are algorithmically equivalent because every one is a particular case of another

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Notice that
$$
y^p-x^p=\prod_{i=0}^{p-1} (y-\omega^i x)\ .
$$
Therefore
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{p-1} f(x\omega^i)= Res_y (y^p-x^p, f(y))\ .
$$
Where $Res_y$ is the resultant of the polynomials in $y$. The above is just a particular case of the so called Poisson product formula. You can then compute the resultant using for instance Sylvester's determinant formula. 
See the review
http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~alidick/papers/chapter1cd.pdf
by Cattani and Dickenstein
for a nice introduction to resultants and their properties.

Comment: That's a nice result, but I think computing the resultant here is quite slow when $f$ is large, which I need it to be.
What I'm really looking for (perhaps I should have made it more clear) is an efficient way to recover $a$, rather than just an expression.

Comment: @Peter: It is unclear to me what you really want. Is there (1) a specific f for which you would like to compute a(x), or do you want (2) a formula for a in terms of a generic f? If it is (1) then the resultant calculation is that of a determinant of order p+deg(f)
with numerical coefficients and a lot of zeros, shouldn't be too bad with a computer algebra software. If it is (2), I don't think you will find a formula for a in terms of undetermined coefficients of f which is simpler that the expansion of the determinant giving the resultant.

Comment: @Peter : there is a division-like algorithm to compute the resultant (well, the division algorithm only works for polynomials over a field, but there is a notion of subresultant polynomial, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subresultant.html which circumvents this difficulty). In general I doubt that there will be a simpler formula than the one given by Abdelmalek, unless you have some more information on f.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that $p$ being prime makes any difference. The **later thoughts** below suggest a Lagrange interpolation method which is perhaps the same as the resultant method mentioned by Abdelmalek Abdesselam.

Let $f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^nc_jx^j. $ One might require $c_n=1$ or $c_0=1$ but it is perhaps nicer not to. Then setting $u=x^n,$ $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} f(\omega^ix)=F(u)=\sum_{j=0}^nC_j u^j$.
One can say that

- $C_j$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in the coefficients $c_0,\cdots,c_n$ where each term has total degree $n$
- $C_j$ has a term $\pm(c_j)^n$ and no term $c_j^{n-1}$.
- $C_{n-j}$ is $C_j$ with $c_k$ replaced by $c_{n-k}$
- the roots of $F$ are the $n$th powers of the roots of $f$.

Here $c_n$ is a constant and the other $c_i$ are symmetric polynomials of the $n$ roots $\alpha_i$ of $f$. The $\alpha_i$ can be thought of as formal variables. Then $c_0,\cdots,c_{n-1}$ are also a basis for the ring of all symmetric polynomials in those variables ($\frac{1}{c_n}$ times  a usual basis) . There are other bases for this ring such as $\sigma_k=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i^k$ and the sum of all the terms $\alpha_1^{m_1}\cdots\alpha_n^{m_n}$ with $m_1+\cdots+m_n=k$. Transforming between these bases (more generally, expressing a given symmetric polynomial in terms of them) is a major topic of invariant theory.

In this case, we want to express the $C_i$, which are certain symmetric polynomials in the $\alpha_i^n,$ in terms of the values $c_i$. This must be a well known case. At any rate here are some results:

For $n=4,$

$$C_0=c_0^4$$

$$C_1=(4c_0^3c_4-2c_0^2c_2^2)-(4c_0^2c_3)c_1+(4c_0c_2)c_1^2-c_1^4$$

$$C_2=(6c_0^2c_4^2-8c_0c_1c_3c_4+2c_1^2c_3^2)+(4c_0c_3^2+4c_1^2c_4)c_2-(4c_0c_4+4c_1c_3)c_2^2+c_2^4$$

$$C_3=(4c_4^3c_0-2c_4^2c_2^2)-(4c_4^2c_1)c_3+4(c_4c_2)c_3^2-c_3^4$$

$$C_4=c_4^4$$

while for $n=5$ we have the following (with the others obtainable by symmetry)

$$C_0=c_0^5$$

$$C_1=5c_0^4c_5-(5c_0^3c_4-5c_0^2c_2^2)c_1+(5c_0^2c_3)c_1^2-5c_0^3c_2c_3-(5c_0c_2)c_1^3+c_1^5$$

$${\small C_2=(10c_0^3c_5^2-15c_0^2c_1c_4c_5+5c_0c_1^2c_4^2+5c_0^2c_3^2c_4+10c_0c_1^2c_3c_5-5c_0c_1c_3^3-5c_1^3c_3c_4)}$$ $${ \small+(5c_0^2c_4^2-15c_0^2c_3c_5+5c_1^2c_3^2-5c_0c_1c_3c_4-5c_1^3c_5)c_2}$$ $${\small +(5c_1^2c_4+10c_0c_1c_5+5c_0c_3^2)c_2^2-(5c_0c_4+5c_1c_3)c_2^3+c_2^5}$$

**later thoughts** In general one could consider the problem of producing from a polynomial $f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^nc_jx^j$ a polynomial $F(u)=\sum_{j=0}^nC_j u^j$ whose roots are the $m$th powers $\alpha_i^m$ of the $n$ (unknown) roots of $f$. The solution is the polynomial $\prod_{i=0}^{m-1} f(\tau^ix)$ where now $\tau$ is a primitive $m$th root of unity.  This process might spread out the roots. In the case $m=2$ one has (with $ q$ repeated application) $\alpha_i^{2^q}$ and the [Dandelin–Graeffe method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeffe%27s_method) for finding the roots of a univariate polynomial. Splitting $f$ into its even and odd parts speeds up the computation. The method was also discovered by [Nikolai Ivanovich Lobachevsky](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2304571) and the linked article suggests that his book *Algebra ili Ichislenie Konechnykh Velichin* discussed the general product $\prod_{i=0}^{m-1} f(\omega^ix)$. Perhaps the appropriate manipulations of symmetric polynomials are discussed there.

Since a polynomial of degree $n$  is determined by its values at $n$ points (plus its leading coeffcient) one has the following method (which I doubt is new):
Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $mn$th root of unity and $\omega$ a primitive $m$th root of unity. Then the desired polynomial $F$ satisfies $F(\zeta^j)=f(\omega^j)$ for $0 \le j \le n-1$. Now Lagrange Interpolation can be used. In this case it might be particularly simple.

Answer (score 4):

The transformation
$$
  \mathcal{L}_n : \mathbb{C}(x) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}(x) 
$$
defined by
$$
  \mathcal{L}_n(F(x)) = \sum_{\zeta\in\boldsymbol\mu_n} F(\zeta y)\Big|_{y^n\to x}
$$
is called a (generalized) Landen transformation. If you take $F(x)=1/f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is a polynomial, then the denominator of $\mathcal{L}_n(F(x))$ is more-or-less the product you are studying. See http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5355 (especially Section 8, which is really about $\prod_{\zeta\in\boldsymbol\mu_n} F(\zeta y)\Big|_{y^n\to x}$), as well as the references in that paper.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more general result is shown in Theorem A here

https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/ims/bull47/R4701.pdf

which states:
If $r$ is relatively prime to $n$ then the coefficient of $x^r$ in $\prod_{i=1}^n f(\omega^i x)$ is 0.

(Here $\omega$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, $f$ has rational coefficients.)