# Resultant of a binomial and a trinomial

Tags: matrices, polynomials

Does anyone know of any papers dealing with the resultant of a binomial $x^n+a$ and a trinomial $x^r+bx^s+c$ ?

Even special cases would be of interest.

(The resultant of two binomials is well known.)

Comment: Any reference for the "well-known" result?

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59859/computing-a-polynomial-product-over-roots-of-unity

Comment: Apologies. See Lemma 3 in the 1962 paper "Factorization of Polynomials over Finite Fields" by Richard Swan  https://msp.org/pjm/1962/12-3/pjm-v12-n3-p27-p.pdf

Comment: Crossposted also at [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2653544/11619).

Comment: I did some calculations: For the special case $r=2, s =1, b=-1, c=-1$ (i.e. the fibonacci quadratic polynomial) one gets $\mathrm{Res}(x^n +a, x^2-x-1)=a^2 + \mathrm{Lucas}(n) \cdot a +(-1)^n$, with $(\mathrm{Lucas}(n)) = (1,3,4,7,\ldots)$. Should not be too difficult to prove and could be a starting point for more general cases.